# MS Access SQL: Enumerate results from a many-to-one relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access

Very simply, I have a many-to-one relationship table set in MS Access where I've managed to pull out the distinct values as separate rows. I now need to enumerate these rows.

The query looks like the following (generated by the MS Access Designer - apologies for the formatting):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ValidationRule.ValidationCode AS Rule, Table.Template AS Template
FROM ValidationRule RIGHT JOIN (([Table] INNER JOIN TableVersion ON Table.TableID = TableVersion.TableID) INNER JOIN ValidationScope ON TableVersion.TableVID =   ValidationScope.TableVID) ON ValidationRule.ValidationId = ValidationScope.ValidationID
GROUP BY ValidationRule.ValidationCode, Table.Template
ORDER BY ValidationRule.ValidationCode;
```

So my data looks like:

```
Rule     Template
v0007_m   C 00.01
v0189_h   C 01.00
v0189_h   C 05.01
v3000_i   C 08.00
```

I need to add sequential values to the results as follows:

```
Rule     Template   Sequence
v0007_m   C 00.01   1
v0189_h   C 01.00   1
v0189_h   C 05.01   2 
v3000_i   C 08.00   1
```

What function should I be looking at in MS Access SQL to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the query you have as a separate query called qryValdationRule, this query which builds off that should give you what you need:

```
SELECT qryValidationRule.Rule, qryValidationRule.Template, DCount("*", 'qryValidationRule', "[Rule] = '" & qryValidationRule.Rule & "' AND [Template] <= '" & qryValidationRule.Template & "'") AS Sequence
FROM qryValidationRule
ORDER BY qryValidationRule.Rule, qryValidationRule.Template;
```

We are looking up and getting a count of all records with the same Rule value with an equal or less Template value within the dataset.  This, essentially, gives us a Sequence grouped by Rule.  This only works properly if Template values are distinct across Rule groups, which should be the case because you are pulling a DISTINCT across the CROSS JOIN of tables.  It is not as convenient or flexible as window functions, but will get you what you need.

You may also want to try this method, which may be more efficient:

```
SELECT t1.Rule, t1.Template, COUNT(t2.Template) AS Sequence
FROM qryValidationRule AS t1 INNER JOIN qryValidationRule AS t2 ON t1.Rule = t2.Rule AND t1.Template >= t2.Template
GROUP BY t1.Rule, t1.Template
ORDER BY t1.Rule, t1.Template;
```

**EDIT:** Added an alternative way to find the same data; may be more performant because of JOINing vs. subqueries.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm for generating those values.

Comment: @toadflakz: You're welcome.  I added an alternative method to get this info.  Not sure which is quicker if using a large dataset, but if you see less than stellar efficiency in the original, may be worth it to try the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Use: Count(*) AS Sequence

```
SELECT DISTINCT ValidationRule.ValidationCode AS Rule, Table.Template AS Template, Count(*) AS Sequence
FROM ValidationRule RIGHT JOIN (([Table] INNER JOIN TableVersion ON Table.TableID =     TableVersion.TableID) INNER JOIN ValidationScope ON TableVersion.TableVID =       ValidationScope.TableVID) ON ValidationRule.ValidationId = ValidationScope.ValidationID
GROUP BY ValidationRule.ValidationCode, Table.Template
ORDER BY ValidationRule.ValidationCode;
```

Comment: No, this doesn't generate the right value in Sequence. I get the same value in Sequence for the "v0189_h" example above.